# ODOO : How to get current state of record object?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

There are multiple states added like this:

```
'state':fields.selection([('new', 'New'), ('assigned','Assigneed'), ('in_progress', 'In Progress'),('resolved','Resolved'),('rejected','Rejected'),('closed','Closed')], 'Status')
```

I need to compare the current state of a record object to take appropriate actions.

Is there a method to get the current state of the record object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An environment wraps data for ORM records:

- 'cr', the current database cursor.
- 'uid', the current user id.
- 'context', the current context dictionary.

In new API, *self* will represent/store current/class level information.

*self.state* will give you current state of record. You can use in any ORM method or function/computed fields as well.

For more about [ORM reference](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I wanted.